# Where is the phrase "declaration of" defined in the C standard or else how should it be interpreted?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I wasn't able to find any definition of this phrase in the current standard. Is there any or else how should it be interpreted?

As besides what "declaration" means in English, it's also explicitly defined in the C language too - there is a whole section about it.

Consider this post written in English without any hidden C meanings (if any defined by the C standard).

Thought of the question this way - as a question to an entirely new language. Forget everything you know about "C" and then try answering my question only according the standard and the way it should be read (for which you could help me too).

Maybe it is rather defined somewhere in the Normative references cited in the standard ($2):

> 1 The following referenced documents are indispensable for the
>   application of this document. For dated references, only the edition
>   cited applies. For undated references, the latest edition of the
>   referenced document (including any amendments) applies.
>
> 2 ISO/IEC
>   2382−1:1993, Information technology — Vocabulary — Part 1: Fundamental
>   terms.
>
> 3 ISO 4217, Codes for the representation of currencies and
>   funds.
>
> 4 ISO 8601, Data elements and interchange formats — Information
>   interchange — Representation of dates and times.
>
> 5 ISO/IEC 10646,
>   Information technology — Universal Coded Character Set (UCS).
>
> 6 IEC
>   60559:1989, Binary floating-point arithmetic for microprocessor
>   systems (previously designated IEC 559:1989).
>
> 7 ISO 80000−2,
>   Quantities and units — Part 2: Mathematical signs and symbols to be
>   used in the natural sciences and technology.

More specifically this question was intended to be a prequel to another one - about type-names. Currently their meaning is not specified. Only their syntax is said to be the same as a declaration with omitted identifier (although there is a distinct syntax section for them currently).

So as we figure out the meaning of "declaration of" eventually we would be able to understand how code like this is supposed to be read:

```
void func(struct { int _1, _2; } );

int main()
{
   func((struct { int _1, _2; }){2, 3});
}
```

Because is this compound literal considered to be a *declaration of* a structure which does not include a tag? Where is this said?

As far as I've seen - nowhere.

On the other hand compound literals themselves contain *type-name*.

$6.5.2.5 (p3):

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized **type name**
>   followed by a braceenclosed list of initializers is a compound
>   literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the
>   initializer list.

If we apply the common sense that type-names are declaration without identifiers and that "declaration of x" means a declaration which introduces an identifier with certain type x then everything is ok. But are type-names really declarations?

Yes type names **syntactically** are declarations without identifiers but this is about their **syntax** and nothing else. They are still distinct entity - type names (and not declarations). Quoting 6.7.7 (p2):

> In several contexts, it is necessary to specify a type. This is
>   accomplished using a type name, which is **syntactically a declaration
>   for a function or an object of that type that omits the identifier**.

With all that said are the two types - the function parameter and the type-name in the compound literal the same?

Remember that (from standard) $6.7.2.3(p5):

> Two declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types which are in
>   different scopes or use different tags declare distinct types. **Each
>   declaration of a structure, union, or enumerated type which does not
>   include a tag declares a distinct type.**

That's what I was going to ask but then I saw that "declaration of" is not explicitly assigned meaning anywhere in the paper and I wondered what exactly does it mean.

I'm starting to see this ANSI standard as a whole utter mess which nobody cares to explain in detail.

Comment: You didn't search correctly.

Comment: Well I did search quite some-time but maybe I'm missing something. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: You could start here: [Google search of `C "declaration of"`](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=C%20%22declaration%20of%22&oq=C%20%22declaration%20of%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4499j1j7&safe=active).

Comment: I was rather searching for explanation according the standard paper.

Comment: I think this is a wonderful question when we consider the nature of the c language and how its identifiers have emerged; It would seem that we have somehow forgotten the very root of this beautiful language. As it would seem happens in most all human language over time.

Answer (score 2):

You can search the latest [online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) yourself, but there is no formal definition of the phrase "declaration of"; it simply falls out of standard English usage.

For example,

```
char arr[10];
```

is a declaration, and the thing it declares is a 10-element array of `char`; in other words, it is a *declaration of* an array.

Similarly

```
void foo( void );
```

is a declaration, and the thing it declares is a function that takes no argument and returns `void`; it is a *declaration of* a function.

"*X* is a declaration of *Y*" simply means that the declaration *X* is associated with the entity *Y*, nothing more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Standard says:

C11-§6.7:

> **Syntax**
>   1
>
> ```
> declaration:  
>     declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
>     static_assert-declaration  
>
> declaration-specifiers:
>     storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt   
>     type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt   
>     type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt   
>     function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt   
>     alignment-specifier declaration-specifiersopt  
>
> init-declarator-list:  
>     init-declarator
>     init-declarator-list , init-declarator  
>
> init-declarator:   
>     declarator
>     declarator = initializer
> ```
>
> 5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers.

For example:

```
extern int a;     // Declaration
void foo(int a);  // Declaration  
extern b[10];     // Declaration  

extern int c  = 0                              // Declaration as well as Definition 
int d;                                         // Declaration as well as Definition 
int foo(int a) { printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a)); } // Declaration as well as Definition
```

An example from standard (6.7.6.1/4)

> The **declaration of** the constant pointer `constant_ptr` may be clarified by including a definition for the type "pointer to `int`".
>
> ```
>       typedef int *int_ptr;
>       const int_ptr constant_ptr;
> ```
>
> declares `constant_ptr` as an object that has type "const-qualified pointer to `int`".

Comment: ... as opposed to their *definition*.

Comment: So you think then the meaning of "declaration of" is a common-sense?

Comment: I really don't think quoting the standard does **anything** to explain it.

Comment: @WeatherVane; He said he do not find any meaningful interpretation in the current standard.

Comment: @FISOCPP; Its not common sense. See the grammar of "declaration" mentioned in *syntax*.

Comment: I'm not struggling to understand it. I know exactly what is it. I simply want to know if it's assumed to be like this or the standard have some explanation of it.

Comment: @FISOCPP; "declaration of" appeared at many places in the standard. I added an example.

Comment: Is that a really a fitting definition of a "declaration of" for a language that wrote its own compiler?

Answer (score 0):

The English word "declare" is used in various ways, meaning approximately to "openly state" or to "publicly tell" something. A "declaration" means something like a "public statement", as in "declaration of war" or "declaration of independence".

But like many technical terms, it has a more specific and precise meaning in the C standard. You can look at it syntactically, which just means that a declaration is a syntactical element of a C program, which can occur at certain places in the program, and which follows certain syntactical rules. Or you can look at it semantically, at what it means: a declaration, says the standard, "specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers".

Here is a small part of a C program:

```
smurfed4life / gargle
```

The `/` is an operator and means division, but *what kind of division?* To decide that, we look at `smurfed4life` and `gargle`. They are identifiers, yes, and identifiers are used as names of things, but what things? To find out, we go back to the *declaration*.

Let's say we find these declarations:

```
int smurfed4life;
const float gargle;
```

Now we know that `smurfed4life` is a variable with the data type `int`, so it can be used to store a normal integer. `gargle` is a variable of the type `float`, so it can be used to store a (single-precision) floating-point number. It is also constant. This is what we can learn from the declarations. Now, according to the rules of the C language, the division will be a floating-point division, not an integer division.

Comment: According to the standard? I know what is it. Read my question again (or maybe you can't because my English is not worth it).

Comment: @FISOCPP: The standard says "specifies the interpretation and attributes", and I tried to explain that. I haven't yet found if the standard says something more about "interpretation" or "attributes".

Comment: I'm starting to feel like I'm missing something big here. What I'm talking about is the expression (in English language) "declaration of" - is it explicitly defined somewhere in the standard or it is supposed to be understand without such?

Comment: @FISOCPP: I tried to explain the semantics (that is, meaning), but perhaps it is better to say that a "declaration", as the term is used in the C standard, is a syntactical element of a C program. It can occur at certain places in the program, and it follows certain syntactical rules.